# How to get rid off strange white stripe on input type button?

Tags: html, css

I came across a strange bug where white stripe appears over my button. It looks like this :
[image: white stripe]

Clearing browser cache doesn't help. Html code and css are given below:

```
<li id = "regButtonContainer"><input type = "button"></li>
```

CSS:

```
#regButtonContainer{

 width: 80px;  
 height: 65px;
 margin-left: 25px;
 background-image: url("../img/regBut.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 border: none; 
 background-color: transparent;
 outline: none;
 -webkit-background-size: 100%;
-o-background-size: 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100%;
-ms-background-size: 100%;
-khtml-background-size: 100%;
background-size: 100%}
```

Comment: Can you link to the problem or provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: @88MPG i have no permision to share code more than that.=/

Comment: You should remove those spaces around your equal signs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by giving button ID and decorating IT with same CSS code.